# Can a COM exposed .NET object that is assigned to a STA have multiple threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, com, interop

In the past few days I've read some very good articles about COM and interoperability.
But there are two statements that confuse me a little bit.

The [microsoft interop documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/interop-marshaling#marshaling-and-com-apartments) says:

> An exported managed server with a type library registered by the
> Regasm.exe (Assembly Registration Tool) has a ThreadingModel registry
> entry set to Both. This value indicates that the server can be
> activated in a single-threaded apartment (STA) or a multithreaded
> apartment (MTA). The server object is created in the same apartment as
> its caller, as shown in the following table.
> [image]

In the [microsoft threading documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/managed-and-unmanaged-threading-in-windows#managed-threads-and-com-apartments) I found:

> Managed objects that are exposed to COM behave as if they had
> aggregated the free-threaded marshaler. In other words, they can be
> called from any COM apartment in a free-threaded manner. The only
> managed objects that do not exhibit this free-threaded behavior are
> those objects that derive from ServicedComponent or
> StandardOleMarshalObject.
>
> *...*
>
> When an unmanaged thread enters the runtime through, for example, a
> COM callable wrapper, the system checks the thread-local store of that
> thread to look for an internal managed Thread object. If one is found,
> the runtime is already aware of this thread. If it cannot find one,
> however, the runtime builds a new Thread object and installs it in the
> thread-local store of that thread.

Maybe I don't understand what **behave as if they had aggregated the free-threaded marshaler** means.
But does this mean that when a .NET object is created in a STA it still behaves like an object with Threading Model **'Free'**?

In my understanding, roughly speaking, all the above citations mean the following:
Regardless of the Apartment type of the calling thread (STA, MTA) a .NET object can create multiple threads as it is managed by the CLR and therefore it doesn't have to follow the COM thread model rules.

Or even simpler: In my managed .NET library I can create as many threads as I want even though the calling process is a single threaded VB6 application.

Is this somehow correct?

Comment: a .NET object can create and use threads the way it sees fit. It's only when .NET/COM borders are crossed that COM rules are followed. However, creating objects in libraries often pose other issues (independent from COM): what happens to the running threads if/when the library is unloaded? etc.

Comment: Good point mentioning the unload behavior. In this case I think of something like a "FinishLib" function in the library which is called when the application is closed. It takes care to terminate running threads or free other resources which are allocated.

Comment: Reading back my comment I see I made a typo I meant "creating threads in libraries". but it looks like you got it right :-) anyway, yes, if you control the client and the server there are ways to ease this out.